# Does a continuous Gaussian process with positive definite covariance function have full support?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, gaussian

In finite dimensions, a Gaussian distribution has full support if and only if its covariance matrix is positive definite. I am now wondering whether this holds true also for the infinite-dimensional case, i.e. for Gaussian processes.

More precisely, let $T$ be a compact metric space (possibly separable and complete if necessary) and $X$ a Gaussian process in $C(T,\mathbb{R})$ with continuous mean function $m\colon T\to \mathbb{R}$ and positive definite covariance function $K\colon T\times T\to \mathbb{R}$. Then the distribution of $X$ is a probability measure on the Borel sets of $C(T,\mathbb{R})$. Does this measure have full support? If not, are there some further assumptions on $T$, $m$, and $K$ which would imply this?

By support of a measure I mean the complement of the largest open set with measure zero.

If a similar statement does hold true, I would be grateful for a proof or a source where I can find one.

Comment: Consider the case of Brownian motion on $T = \mathbb R$. It has continuous paths, continuous mean function, and positive-definite covariance, since all finite-dimensional distributions have full support. Yet any open ball centered on the upward drift path $x(t) = t$ has zero Brownian measure, since Brownian motion almost surely has $\liminf_{t \to \infty} B_t = -\infty$.

Comment: @nahp Good point, so compactness of $T$ is definitely necessary.